# jquery dialog window - set options once as a variable

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a page that has a bunch of different dialog window selectors.  The options (width,height,etc...) are the same for all of them.  Instead of setting those options each instance of the selector, I want to set the variable "options" once, and use that variable through out page.  How can i accomplish this?

```
var options = "autoOpen:false,width:100,height:100";

$('#dialog').dialog(options);

$('#dialog2').dialog(options);

 //etc......
```

edit:  how can i write out the options line without it being 1203123 characters long? multiple lines?

```
     var options = {autoOpen:false,width:1000,height:1000,position {my:'top',at:'top'},show:{effect:'fade',speed:1000},hide:{effect:'slideUp',speed:2000}};
```

that becomes difficult to read....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below procedure:

```
var options = "autoOpen:false,width:100,height:100";
$('#dialog').dialog({ options });
```

You need to specify multiple options in `{ }` brackets in jquery,as elements of an object.

**Edited:**
       The below is another better method to do it.

```
    var options = {autoOpen:false,width:100,height:100};
    $('#dialog').dialog(options);
```

**Answer for extended edit in the question**

```
position = {my:'top',at:'top'};
show     = {effect:'fade',speed:1000};
hide     = {effect:'slideUp',speed:2000};
var options = {autoOpen:false,width:1000,height:1000,position:position  ,show:show,hide:hide}
```

Comment: I dont see the options being applied to the dialog.

Comment: have a look at the another solution provided in the edited method

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

var options = {"autoOpen":"false","width":"100","height":"100" };

Answer (score 0):

You can override your `Dialog options` with this little piece of code below:

```
 $.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
 });
```

Look this example:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/omnutxse/)